# How to pass value from js to hidden_field in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mapbox

I use rails 5.2 and mapbox for geocoding

I try to pass latitude and longitude from js but nothing works

I can't understand what is the reason why it does not work

my code:

```
<%= form_for(@place, :remote => true, html: { role: 'form', multiple: true }) do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :longitude %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :latitude %>
  <div class="margin-top-40">
    <div id='map' style='height: 300px;'></div>
    <script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'accessToken';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
        });

        var lng;
        var lat;
        var lngDisplay = document.getElementById('place_longitude');
        var latDisplay = document.getElementById('place_latitude');

        var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
          'color': '#314ccd'
        });

        map.on('click', function(e) {

          marker.setLngLat(e.lngLat).addTo(map);

          lng = e.lngLat.lng;
          lat = e.lngLat.lat;

          lngDisplay.textContent = lng;
          latDisplay.textContent = lat;
        });
    </script>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit 'Save', data: {disable_with: 'Save...'}, class: 'btn btn-s'%>
    <%= link_to 'Back', :back, class: 'btn btn-d' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: where in the code are you placing the values into those hidden fields?  The only `onClick` I see doesn't seem to be doing that.  Can you tell me the ids of the two hidden fields?

Comment: @RockwellRice         `var lngDisplay = document.getElementById('place_longitude');
        var latDisplay = document.getElementById('place_latitude');` ids: 'place_longitude', 'place_latitude'

Comment: `<%= f.hidden_field :longitude, :id=>"place_longitude" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :latitude,:id=>"place_longitude" %>` add these

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan This will not help Rails already generated this ids

Comment: can u console the value of lng and lat in your on click function

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan `<input id="place_longitude" type="hidden" value="" name="place[longitude]">4.928367069077325
<input id="place_latitude" type="hidden" value="" name="place[latitude]">51.613135708889615`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what was the problem

```
lngDisplay.textContent = lng;
latDisplay.textContent = lat;
```

Need to change to:

```
  lngDisplay.value = lng;
  latDisplay.value = lat;
```